# C# EF Code first - init database (create table) and enable migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm updating a webform app to a mvc app but I have an issue.

I would like to create automatically the AspNetUsers tables when I try, for the first time,to log in through the webApp

Below the error messages:

- **The target context 'PROJECT.Data.DataContext' is not constructible.
  Add a default constructor or provide an implementation of
  IDbContextFactory.**
- **Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for
  databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations.**

The first one is fired with the code below:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DataContext, MyConfiguration>());

    public class MyConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DataContext>
    {
        public MyConfiguration()
        {
            this.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        }

        protected override void Seed(DataContext context)
        {
            InitializeIdentityForEF(context);
            base.Seed(context);
        }

        public void InitializeIdentityForEF(DataContext db)
        {
           // create admin user with role and claims
        }
    }
```

The second one:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new ApplicationDbInitializer());

 public class ApplicationDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DataContext>
 {

      protected override void Seed(DataContext context)
      {
           InitializeIdentityForEF(context);
           base.Seed(context);
      }

      public void InitializeIdentityForEF(DataContext db)
      {
           // create admin user with role and claims
      }
}
```

I think that I can fix this issue if I enable the the migration through the console but I would like to implement everything in the code. Any idea to mix theses two code above?

NOTE: I just want to create the AspNetUser table because I'm using "Database First" once they are created.

```
public class DataContext : DbContext, IEntitiesContext
    {
        private static readonly object Lock = new object();
        private static bool _databaseInitialized;

        public DataContext(string nameOrConnectionString, ILogger logger) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
        {
            Database.Log = logger.Log;
            if (_databaseInitialized)
            {
                return;
            }
            lock (Lock)
            {
                if (!_databaseInitialized)
                {
                    Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DataContext, MyConfiguration>());
                    Database.SetInitializer(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
                    _databaseInitialized = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't see any code used to define `DataContext` (possible `DbContext` throwing the error). Check if you have a class which implements `IDbContextFactory<DataContext>` & ensure you have `Create` method which returning `DataContext` (`return new DataContext("connectionString")`).

Comment: Actually, I have DataContex.cs

Comment: Where is the DbSet<model> located?

Comment: Inside DataContext.cs                                                                             public new IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : BaseEntity
        {
            return base.Set<TEntity>();
        }

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but can you include that here? so we can Identify really. BTW please include the codes for the DbSet config.